# Make cell in Excel mandatory (prevent save) - without macro

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to prevent an Excel document from being saved if a particular cell (say `F5`) is not filled out. However, I cannot use a macro, as I'm providing this document to users to fill it out as a form. If the user does not enable macros, the macro will be pointless. I need to be able to do this without a macro.

The Data Validation option is unacceptable as if I initially leave the field blank (don't touch it in the first place) then it doesn't warn the user.

Is it possible to do this without a macro?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer -- No, it's not possible without using VBA.

Even with VBA, it would be easy to prevent the user from doing a "Save As" but difficult to prevent him from doing a regular "Save." For instance: the user has AutoSave enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Conditional Formatting, like have a big red border around the cell, until a value is entered.

Comment: This is a good way to show what still needs to be done